# Mounting an HFS + External Drive

Tags: windows, macos, mount, hfs+

I have a Windows computer at home, and a company sent me an external HDD formatted as HFS+.

It doesn't read on my Windows machine. I'm planning to use a software called Paragon to access the files, but when I open it, it prompts me to mount the drive.

Is it safe to do so? This external HDD contains sensitive files, and I'm concerned about losing information. What are the implications of mounting this drive? Will it change its format or risk losing information if I proceed?"

Comment: Have you asked your company IT?

Comment: I did they asked me to try on a mac instead of mounting on windows. But i would like to know what would happen with mounting the drive.

Answer (score 1):

If it's safe (for the PC) to mount on a Mac, it's just as safe to mount on a PC.

Just reading (copying) from the drive should cause no change in the data on it whatsoever, but opening a file on it in an application *could cause issues*. For example, when opening a .docx document in MS *Word* or LibreOffice *Writer*, a lock file is written to the disk.

[image: Lock file]

My experience has been that programs, such as [HFS+ for Windows](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/hfs-windows/#) by Paragon Software, free [hfsexplorer](https://www.catacombae.org/hfsexplorer/) from Catacombae, or [alternatives](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/4-ways-read-mac-formatted-drive-windows/), can *read* from a drive in another file system format (ext4 and btrfs also come to mind), but **writing to that foreign file system is problematic.** Some of these applications do not implement writing, which is safest, and some *attempt* to write, but often cause issues with the file system.

So use whatever application you wish to mount the HFS+ drive and to copy data, but don't try to otherwise use data on that drive.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply! Great answer!